# Issue when setting visibility of LinearLayout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, visibility

Relevant XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_video_feed_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_video_feed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Relevant CODE:

```
linearLayoutVideoFeedListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_video_feed_list_view);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_video_feed)
```

`lv.setVisibility(GONE)` works but `linearLayoutVideoFeedListView.setVisibility(GONE)` causes nullpointer exception. Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you calling `linearLayoutVideoFeedListView.setVisibility(GONE)` after `lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_video_feed)`?

Comment: Can you hide a root view if its the top most parent?

Comment: @Spidy the `linearLayoutVideoFeedListView` is not the root view. It is wrapped in another `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If linear_layout_video_feed_list_view has not been laid out before you call

> linearLayoutVideoFeedListView.setVisibility(GONE)

it will result in a Null Pointer.
If this is indeed the problem here, try inflating it:

> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>   RelativeLayout myView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.id.linear_layout_video_feed_list_view, null);

Hope that helps

Comment: When declaring mContext and mInflater: Context mContext; what type is mInflater?

Comment: And another thought, the `linearLayoutVideoFeedListView` must be laid out because I can call `lv.setVisibility(GONE)` which is nested inside of `linearLayoutVideoFeedListView`. Right?

Answer (score -2):

I would try

```
linearLayoutVideoFeedListView.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
```

thats what has always worked for me

Comment: I tried it and I'm still getting the NullPointerException. Any other ideas? Thanks.